ESBuild always fails with the signal SIGSEGV
Every time I try to install most packages, they fail with the signal SIGSEGV. I've tried everything, every solution on google, uninstalling and reinstalling node, etc. Nothing works. I have no errors with nothing else. This error started when I installed Endeavour OS yesterday, and node just hasn't worked even though it works fine on literally everything else.
Extra Info:
My project is stored on a NTFS drive, and for some reason every time I use it, I have to use ntfsfix.
I'm cloning the project from the Github Desktop app.
I'm using vscode.
I have the NPM version 10.9.2, and the node version v20.11.1
I've tried the lts, v18, v20.11.1, the latest version, and none of them work.
System info:
https://imgur.com/a/OOx5KRc
The error:
[solarity@solarity-ms7c91 solarmath]$ npm i astro
npm error code 1
npm error path /run/media/solarity/Data/Documents/Github/solarmath/node_modules/astro/node_modules/esbuild
npm error command failed
npm error command sh -c node install.js
npm error node:internal/errors:932
npm error   const err = new Error(message);
npm error               ^
npm error
npm error Error: Command failed: /run/media/solarity/Data/Documents/Github/solarmath/node_modules/astro/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild --version
npm error     at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:890:11)
npm error     at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:926:15)
npm error     at validateBinaryVersion (/run/media/solarity/Data/Documents/Github/solarmath/node_modules/astro/node_modules/esbuild/install.js:99:28)
npm error     at /run/media/solarity/Data/Documents/Github/solarmath/node_modules/astro/node_modules/esbuild/install.js:283:5 {
npm error   status: null,
npm error   signal: 'SIGSEGV',
npm error   output: [ null, Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [], Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [] ],
npm error   pid: 186382,
npm error   stdout: Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
npm error   stderr: Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] []
npm error }
npm error
npm error Node.js v20.11.1
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/solarity/.npm/_logs/2024-12-14T17_45_33_426Z-debug-0.log
[solarity@solarity-ms7c91 solarmath]$ [solarity@solarity-ms7c91 solarmath]$ npm i astro
npm error code 1
npm error path /run/media/solarity/Data/Documents/Github/solarmath/node_modules/astro/node_modules/esbuild
npm error command failed
npm error command sh -c node install.js
npm error node:internal/errors:932
npm error   const err = new Error(message);
npm error               ^
npm error
npm error Error: Command failed: /run/media/solarity/Data/Documents/Github/solarmath/node_modules/astro/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild --version
npm error     at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:890:11)
[solarity@solarity-ms7c91 solarmath]$ an be found in: /home/solarity/.npm/_logs/2024-12-14T17_45_33_426Z-debug-0.log.js:283:5 {uild/install.js:99:28)

